# Distinct on an array in scala returns an empty string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-graphx, databricks

I am trying to learn graphx on from this code [click here](https://github.com/caroljmcdonald/sparkgraphxexample/blob/master/Graphx_Shell_2.scala) in GitHub

On the spark-shell, when I try this:

```
def parseFlight(str: String): Flight = {
  val line = str.split(",")
  Flight(line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3), line(4).toInt, line(5).toLong, line(6), line(7).toLong, line(8), line(9).toDouble, line(10).toDouble, line(11).toDouble, line(12).toDouble, line(13).toDouble, line(14).toDouble, line(15).toDouble, line(16).toInt)
}

val textRDD = sc.textFile("/user/user01/data/rita2014jan.csv")

val flightsRDD = textRDD.map(parseFlight).cache()

val airports = flightsRDD.map(flight => (flight.org_id, flight.origin)).distinct

airports.take(1)
```

I get this exception which points at `airports.take(1)`:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

Can anyone let me know if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most probably comes from a row within your input in which a field you're casting to Double is empty.

The error most likely comes from this function (applied at the begining of the spark pipeline):

```
def parseFlight(str: String): Flight = {
  val line = str.split(",")
  Flight(line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3), line(4).toInt, line(5).toLong, line(6), line(7).toLong, line(8), line(9).toDouble, line(10).toDouble, line(11).toDouble, line(12).toDouble, line(13).toDouble, line(14).toDouble, line(15).toDouble, line(16).toInt)
}
```

At some point a cast `.toDouble` is applied on `""` (an empty String).

---

For instance you can reproduce the same error by doing this:

```
"aa,,,s".split(",")(2).toDouble
```

which produces:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

---

The error led you to think it comes from the line which contains `airports.take(1)` because it's the line which contains the first `action` of your pipeline (this is where the laziness of the RDD is lost - as opposed to transformations such as map).